# Function to access own object properties in function

Tags: javascript

From `getValuePerTick()` how do I access `maxValue` and `numberOfTicks`? Trying my hand at my first JavaScript program and having some trouble. Thanks!

```
var TChart = Object.extend(
{
    init: function(canvasName)
    {
       // ...
       this.config = {
                gutter: {
                    top: 25,
                    right: 100,
                    bottom: 50,
                    left: 0
                },
                scale: {
                    maxValue: 3.3,
                    numberOfTicks: 10,
                    getValuePerTick: function() {
                        return (maxValue / numberOfTicks);
                    }
                }
            };
         // ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `maxValue` and `numberOfTicks` are properties of the object, you need to use member notation to access it

```
   this.config = {
            gutter: {
                top: 25,
                right: 100,
                bottom: 50,
                left: 0
            },
            scale: {
                maxValue: 3.3,
                numberOfTicks: 10,
                getValuePerTick: function() {
                    return (this.maxValue / this.numberOfTicks);
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply with `this.` prefix

```
return (this.maxValue / this.numberOfTicks);
```